# Do I need to complete the cookie domain and path information in Joomla?

Tags: joomla-2.5, configuration, cookies

In the Joomla backend, under Global configuration -> Site I have the following cookie setting information
[image]

My Joomla website seems to work fine without having completed the cookie fields, so my questions are as follows

1. Is it safe for me to leave this information blank?
2. If yes, under what situations would I need to fill it out? (and)
3. How would I fill it out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default behavior is like this:

- **Cookie Domain**: Joomla will use an empty value and the cookie will be valid for the current domain.
- **Cookie Path**: Joomla will use `/` as default value and the cookie will be valid for the whole site.

Thus usually, the default values will be fine.

The cookie domain may be useful if you want a cookie be valid for several subdomains. The cookie path would have to be set if the cookie should only be valid for a certain subdirectory.

Comment: I'm not sure how Joomla works in this respect, but if an "empty value" is passed as the cookie domain to PHP's `setcookie()` function or `Set-Cookie` response header then the browser will set a cookie on the current _host only_ eg. `www.example.com` (excluding any subdomains), not necessarily the current domain eg. `.example.com`.

Answer (score 2):

The ‘Domain’ Attribute
• With domain set, cookies will be sent to that domain
and all its subdomains
• The risk with subdomains is lower than when scoped to
parent domain, but still relevant
• Remove domain attribute to limit cookie to origin host
only
– Important note: IE will always send to subdomains regardless

Comment: Welcome to the community.  Thank you for contributing.  Please take the [tour] and look for more pages that you can offer support to.